# How to pass a call to tx.scheduler.schedule?

Tags: polkadot-js, call

I am attempting to submit `tx.scheduler.schedule` as follows:

```js
const wasm = await readFile(file)
const call = api.tx.parachainSystem.enactAuthorizedUpgrade(wasm)
await api.tx.scheduler
  .schedule(
    53, 
    null, 
    1, 
    call
  )
  .signAndSend(sudo)
```

When I `console.debug` the `call` it looks like:

```
Submittable { initialU8aLength: undefined }
```

Submitting the extrinsic fails with:

```
Error: createType(Call):: Call: failed decoding scheduler.schedule
:: Struct: failed on args:{"when":"u32","maybe_periodic":"Option<(u32,u32)>","priority":"u8","call":"{\"_enum\":{\"Value\":\"Call\",\"Hash\":\"H256\"}}"}
:: Struct: failed on call: {"_enum":{"Value":"Call","Hash":"H256"}}
:: Cannot map Enum JSON, unable to find 'initialU8aLength' in value, hash
```

What do I need to do to the embedded call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call parameter is [an enum, MaybeHashed](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/50176e1b57bdf6168d9bf3764d1cce9ed8bcf611/frame/scheduler/src/lib.rs#L85) for either a `Call` or a `Hash`, as the error message suggests which provides the type -

```js
"call":"{\"_enum\":{\"Value\":\"Call\",\"Hash\":\"H256\"}}"
```

To call it, you need to explicitly indicate the fact that you are making a call by passing the enum with a value instead of the call itself.

Adjust your code to the following -

```js
await api.tx.scheduler
  .schedule(
    53, 
    null, 
    1, 
    // pass an enum here - `call` as the type 
    { value: call }
  )
  .signAndSend(...)
```

In the same way when passing a hash you would do `{ hash: '0x...' }`